# Javascript regex replace character if preceded AND followed by a letter

Tags: javascript, json, regex

Basically I am working with a string that is a json string in python but when used in javascript it has the "'" tags instead of double quotes and I would like to turn it into a real json (by using the JSON.parse()) but there are some quotation marks in the middle of the sentences (because I replaced the "'" for double marks).

Example: '{"author": "Jonah D"Almeida", ... }'
(I want to replace the one in between D and Almeida)

As it already has quotation marks around the whole sentence, javascript gives an error because it can't create a json out of it and so, to solve that basically I want to replace the quotation mark in the middle of the sentence for a ' (single mark) but only if it has letters preceeding and following the quotation mark.

My thought: `myString.replace('letter before ... " ... letter after', "'")`

Any idea how can I get the right expression for this? Basically I just want to know the regex expression the check if before and after the " quote it has letters, and if yes, change it to single mark (').

Comment: parsing **valid** JSON data will return a perfectly valid object, and in case of the OP's use case a correctly escaped string value as well.

Comment: where does this invalid JSON format come from?

Comment: I have a valid json in python but then when I use it in javascript it comes with the '&#x27;' parts that I have to replace by ". But as one of this replacements is inside the sentence, I would like to replace it with ' instead of "

Comment: I edited my answer according to the OP's sanitizing requirements which are ... replace and/or escape(?) any *"[double quote] character [which is] preceded and followed by a letter"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The OP ... *"Basically I am working with a string that is a json string"*

The above example is not what the OP refers to as *json string*. The OP's example data string already is invalid JSON.

Thus the first thing was to fix the process which generates such data.

Because ...

> *"parsing **valid** JSON data will return a perfectly valid object, and in case of the OP's use case a correctly escaped string value as well. "*

... proof ...

```js
const testSample_A = { author: "Jonah D'Almeida" };
const testSample_B = { author: 'Jonah D"Almeida' };
const testSample_C = { author: 'Jonah D\'Almeida' };
const testSample_D = { author: "Jonah D\"Almeida" };

console.log({
  testSample_A,
  testSample_B,
  testSample_C,
  testSample_D,
});
console.log('JSON.stringify(...) ... ', {
  testSample_A: JSON.stringify(testSample_A),
  testSample_B: JSON.stringify(testSample_B),
  testSample_C: JSON.stringify(testSample_C),
  testSample_D: JSON.stringify(testSample_D),
});
console.log('JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)) ... ', {
  testSample_A: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(testSample_A)),
  testSample_B: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(testSample_B)),
  testSample_C: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(testSample_C)),
  testSample_D: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(testSample_D)),
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Edit**

A sanitizing task which exactly follows the OP's requirements nevertheless can be achieved based on a regex which features both a positive [lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookahead) and a positive [lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) ... either for basic latin only [`/(?<=\w)"(?=\w)/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/Ews1Ra/2) or more international with [unicode escapes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) ... [`/(?<=\p{L})"(?=\p{L})/gmu`](https://regex101.com/r/Ews1Ra/1)

```js
console.log('Letter unicode escapes ...', `
  {"author": "Jonah D"Almeida", ... }
  {"author": "Jon"ah D"Almeida", ... }
  {"author": "Jon"ah D"Alme"ida", ... }`
    .replace(/(?<=\p{L})"(?=\p{L})/gmu, '\\"')
);
console.log('Basic Latin support ...', `
  {"author": "Jonah D"Almeida", ... }
  {"author": "Jon"ah D"Almeida", ... }
  {"author": "Jon"ah D"Alme"ida", ... }`
    .replace(/(?<=\w)"(?=\w)/gm, '\\"')
);

console.log(
  'sanitized and parsed string data ...',
  JSON.parse(`[
    { "author": "Jonah D"Almeida" },
    { "author": "Jon"ah D"Almeida" },
    { "author": "Jon"ah D"Alme"ida" }
  ]`.replace(/(?<=\p{L})"(?=\p{L})/gmu, '\\"'))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The last edition you did was exactly the thing I was looking for. But I changed the letter being replace from ' \\" ' to " ' " since I wanted to change the double quote to a single one only on "inside the sentences" quotes. Thanks a lot